# Can I buy Serbian train tickets online?

Tags: trains, online-resources, serbia, montenegro

I want to go from Belgrade to Podgorica by train on June 2017.

Is it possible to buy a ticket online? If it is not possible, what are the chances to buy the ticket just before the trip (I arrive in Belgrade at noon and I'd like to leave Podgorica at evening)?

Comment: The bus may be faster.

Comment: +1 for the bus. While not what you asked, the train is certainly *not* the kind of transportation you want if you just want to get to Podgorica from Belgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The man in Seat 61](http://seat61.com/index.html) is your friend when in comes to train travel just about anywhere in the world.

Your chosen itinerary is on the apparently greatly scenic [Belgrad - Bar line. For that he has to say](http://seat61.com/belgrade-to-bar-railway.htm):

- > Engineering work to renovate & speed up the line is happening in 2017.  The night train Lovcen is cancelled until 1 July 2017.  They day train Tara will run, but passengers will be conveyed by bus rather than train for the first 68 km of the journey between Belgrade & Lajkovac.
- > You can book a southbound train from Belgrade to Montenegro either at the station or by emailing the highly-recommended Mr Popovic in Belgrade [as shown here](http://seat61.com/Serbia.htm#Booking-trains-in-Serbia).  The limited online reservation system at www.serbianrailways.com now seems to have disappeared.

That option allows you to get cheap advance fares instead of the full fare tickets:

- > The Serbian Railways reservation system is linked to the western European railway computer reservation systems, so seat, couchette or sleeper reservations can be made on domestic or international trains starting in Belgrade from most reservation offices or train booking agencies across Europe, including UK European rail booking agencies.  In practice however, the computer link sometimes goes down, and in any case agencies outside Serbia can usually only sell full-price 'TCV' tariff tickets, not the various cheap special offer fares that are available locally.